# Cannot read property 'length' of null when calling .length

Tags: javascript

- I have programmed a small function which takes in x's and o's. If there are the same number of each letter in a string, the function returns true
- My problem is I am trying to get this test to pass in `code wars` and the tests are returning:

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at XO

Why is this the case? What can I do to resolve this?

```
    function XO(str) {
      x = str.match(/[x]/gi).length
      y = str.match(/[o]/gi).length



       return x == y ? true : false 
    }
```

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): _"If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by any results captured in parentheses. **If there were no matches, `null` is returned**."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for alternate and null values being passed to the function  - also you can ignore the ternary equation in the return and simply return the outcome of the comparison operator.

```js
console.log(XO('x')); // returns false since there is 1 'x' and 0 'o'
console.log(XO('o')); // returns false since there is 0 'x' and 1 'o'
console.log(XO('abc')); // returns true since there is 0 'x' and 0 'o'

function XO(str) {
 if(str) {
    x = str.match(/[x]/gi) || [];
    y = str.match(/[o]/gi) || [];
    return x.length == y.length;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Andreas - answer amended to account for the variations  - adding an empty array (length = 0) instead of "null" so that a comparison can then be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
function XO(str) {
      var x = str.match(/[x]/gi) && str.match(/[x]/gi).length;
      var y = str.match(/[o]/gi) && str.match(/[o]/gi).length;
      return x == y;
}
```

The first condition in AND statement will check for `null` or `undefined` then if it is not null then only it will calculate the `length` of the matched items.

Comment: **Four** regex operations are at least two too much

Comment: What are you trying to say? @Andreas

Comment: Have you heard of "variables", Ankit?

Comment: Better, but you're still repeating the same regex operation more than needed.

Comment: How @NiettheDarkAbsol?